# Extracting audio features

Tags: python, ffmpeg, azure-media-services, librosa, aws-mediaservices

I am working on extracting features from an audio file to build a recommendation system.

So far I am able to extract tempo, beat-times, loudness and pitch class using librosa and ffmpeg.

My question how we can extract/detect features as Danceability, Energy, Acousticness, Speechiness, Valence without using Spotify API. Are there any libraries or algorithm using which we can do so.

Comment: I am voting to close this for the reason "**Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more**". [help/on-topic]: "Questions asking us to _recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_ are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: No.  Do you understand how totally subjective those things are?  And none of them has any standardized definition.  I'm not convinced a machine COULD decide any of those.  My guess is that Spotify is returning polling data that was created by human listeners.

Answer (score 1):

It is depending on Which API you are using to get the Audio Features.
Currently, except for **Spotify**, we **don't** have other APIs to get the features like (**Danceability, Energy, Acousticness, Speechiness, Valence**).

Using [essentia](https://hpac.cs.umu.se/teaching/sem-mus-17/Reports/Paranjape.pdf) Package we can get the Danceability Feature.

Refer [Deep learning music information retrieval](https://labs-repos.iit.demokritos.gr/MagCIL/theses/2020_MSc_Thesis_Karydis_Athanasios.pdf)